# Flutter: Zoom and pan a widget

Tags: flutter, zooming, pan

I'm fighting with zoom/pan gestures.
I've found a partially suitable example in this book:

https://books.google.bg/books?id=ex-tDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA284&lpg=PA284&dq=flutter+_startLastOffset&source=bl&ots=YUQna09jIf&sig=ACfU3U0QrHwl2RdrVUv5EtpHaHFKx_cXhA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwid9uPJ8abnAhVnlosKHTKQBn4Q6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=flutter%20_startLastOffset&f=false

which, I guess was based on this:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/flutter/flutter/+/refs/heads/dev/examples/layers/widgets/gestures.dart

And my code based on it:

```
Offset _startLastOffset = Offset.zero;
Offset _lastOffset = Offset.zero;
Offset _currentOffset = Offset.zero;
double _lastScale = 1.0;
double _currentScale = 1.0;

void _onScaleStart(ScaleStartDetails details) {
  _startLastOffset = details.focalPoint;
  _lastOffset = _currentOffset;
  _lastScale = _currentScale;
}

void _onScaleUpdate(ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
  if (details.scale != 1.0) {
    // Scaling
    double currentScale = _lastScale * details.scale;
    if (currentScale < 0.5) {
      currentScale = 0.5;
    }
    _currentScale = currentScale;
    _bloc.setScale(_currentScale);
  } else if (details.scale == 1.0) {
    // We are not scaling but dragging around screen
    // Calculate offset depending on current Image scaling.
    Offset offsetAdjustedForScale = (_startLastOffset - _lastOffset) / _lastScale;
    Offset currentOffset = details.focalPoint - (offsetAdjustedForScale * _currentScale);
    _currentOffset = currentOffset;
    _bloc.setOffset(_currentOffset);
  }
}
---------------
child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
  stream: _bloc.scale,
  builder: (context, snapshot1) {
    double _cscale = snapshot1.hasData? snapshot1.data : _currentScale;
    return StreamBuilder<Object>(
      stream: _bloc.offset,
      builder: (context, snapshot2) {
        Offset _coffset = snapshot2.hasData? snapshot2.data : _currentOffset;
        return Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.identity()
            ..scale(_cscale, _cscale)
            ..translate(_coffset.dx, _coffset.dy),
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: Stack(
            key: _imgStack,
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/image.png')),
              SvgPicture.asset(svgFile)
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
),
```

The Pan of which, however, behaves unnatural when the widget is zoomed - the widget moves much further than the finger, in the moving direction.

I managed to fix this by changing:

```
_currentOffset = currentOffset;
_bloc.setOffset(_currentOffset);
```

to:

```
_bloc.setOffset(currentOffset/_currentScale);
_currentOffset = currentOffset;
```

Which works exactly as expected, but just until the Second zoom.
After the second time I zoom, the widget get shifted on first touch.
On zoom-in it shifts to the right, on zoom-out it shifts to the left.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`InteractiveViewer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html) widget. Here is an example.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: InteractiveViewer(
      boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(100),
      minScale: 0.1,
      maxScale: 1.5,
      child: Container(width: 200, height: 200, color: Colors.blue),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: InteractiveViewer does not work properly with CarouselSlider. If we want to see left or right portion of an image then slider shows previous image or next image respectevely. Do you have any suggestion? how can we fix it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kamlesh Sorry, I haven't used that package yet.

Comment: Ok, no worry, could you please suggest me any solution so that if child widget width/height is greater than parent widget width/height then child widget should not display/go out side of parent widget. Please share your thoughts or previous experience. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh I'm not sure what your widgets are, but you can give a try to `SingleChildScrollView` by setting the scroll direction to horizontal.